# Can I get a versioned recovery from a VIM swap file?

Tags: vim, backup, swap, recovery

I have a file x.cpp which a while ago contained, say, "AAAAAAA".

I accidentally copied over it with another file containing, say, "BBBBBBB".

PANIC!

Hang on, let's look at .x.cpp.swp -- there's a load of binary junk then "BBBBBBB" then more junk then "AAAAAAA", so it looks like the swap file contains both versions. Hooray!

So, how do I recover the "AAAAAAAA" version? If I do `vim -r` then I get "BBBBBBB". Unfortunately, I can't recover-then-hit-undo. Is there an incantation? Can I hack the swap file?

Massive gratitude if you know a trick here.

Comment: is it too big a file to manually delete the BBBBB part?

Comment: do you have a vim backup? (the `~` files)?

Comment: 1: Use version control. 2: If you are looking for recognizable text _and_ the swapfile contained it, you'd use `strings swapfile.swp` to extract 'readable' strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but if you use Vim 7.3+ you can enable undofiles

To get started:

```
:he undo-persistence
```

That way you can navigate the undo tree even after a (involuntary) close of your editor.

So yes, the usual trick of going back in time, yanking, going forward in time, pasting will work even after the editor was restarted.

`100g-` (locate text, yank into register), `100g+` (locate destination, put register).

Comment: Why would anyone not want this? This should be on by default. Thanks.

Comment: @masterxilo People who like to use version control for that, and who prefer e.g. that `999999u` always brings back the state to when the buffer was opened, not to some point back in 2009 (this happened to me once)